# Editar o nome do AplicationId no android Studio

Tags: android

Boa tarde,

Estou tentando publicar um app no google play, mas aparace o seguinte erro:

> Use um nome de pacote diferente. "com.example" é restrito.

Já alterei (manualmente) o nome do pacote, mas depois que fiz isso apareceu o seguinte erro:

```
pkg: /data/local/tmp/nome do meu projeto(alterado)

Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_CONFLICTING_PROVIDER]"
```

Estou usando o Android Studio.

Answer (score 1):

Uma boa dica (rápida e fácil) é criar um novo pacote e mover tudo para este novo pacote.

- Refaça todo o `rename` do seu pacote, deixe como estava (`com.examplo`).
- Crie um novo pacote, como você quer (por exemplo `br.com.stackoverflow.brasil`) dentro do diretório `java`:

[image: Antigo]

- Agora, mova (segurando e arrastando) todos os pacotes dentro do `com.exemplo` para o `br.com.stackoverflow.brasil` e o `Android Studio` irá mover todas as referências automaticamente:

[image: Novo]

- Agora, atualize o seu pacote no `AndroidManifest.xml`

> package="br.com.stackoverflow.brasil"

- Agora, remova (delete) o pacote vazio `com.exemplo`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Siga esse conteúdo do Google, pode te auxiliar a fazer isso.

http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/applicationid-vs-packagename